# Problems in clustering the data while using Carrot2 API with Lingo3GClusteringAlgorithm

Tags: carrot

I had one scenario where i had to cluster Operating System data.
Actual Data consists of 
     151 users using Windows,27 users using MAC,5 users using Linux.

Once after clustering with Carrot2 API using Lingo3gClusteringAlgorithm.
Getting cluster results as 
   MAC OS users 27 ,Linux users 5 and finally all Windows users are in **Other Topics Cluster**.
But it would be good if i get **Windows** users as a separate Cluster.
So in order to get Windows as a separate cluster what clustering attributes do i need to configure.
Currently using only **"combined-cluster-score-balance"** with value:**1.0**.
Any help is appreciated

Comment: Carrot2 performs unsupervised text-based clustering, so the results will never be perfect. If you could make your data set available somewhere, we could inspect it to see if any further tuning is possible.

Comment: Hey @StanislawOsinski sorry for the late reply. Thanks for your help .Here is the link where I posted the data
https://pastebin.com/VgNUdjdM.                                                      Using the following configs ("combined-cluster-score-balance", "1.0");
      ("active-language", "ENGLISH");
   ("max-cluster-size",1.0);                                                                                  With clustering algorithm as Lingo3GClusteringAlgorithm.class

Answer (score 0):

Both Carrot2 and Lingo3G are **natural text** clustering engines. You'll need at least a dozen of documents consisting of at least a paragraph of text to get sensible results.

Looking at your data, the text fields contain one word, which far too little for our algorithms to succeed. For your specific data you many need some of the generic clustering algorithms suitable for numeric and nominal data. [Mahout](http://mahout.apache.org/) and [WEKA](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/) might be a good start.

Comment: Okay.So, is there any possibility to improve clustering by adding any configs on top of existing based on the data which i provided.

Comment: Unfortunately not, Carrot2 and Lingo3G are not applicable to your data. They require at least a paragraph of natural text to work. Individual words are not enough.